# JMeter higher response times in non-gui

Tags: performance, jmeter

I am running performance tests on an API endpoint, and I've noticed that when I use the GUI version of JMeter, I get lower response times than when I run the tests in non-GUI mode. For example, a simple request with 10 threads will generate the following:

```
GUI:
Samples (threads): 10
Min: 765
Max: 853

NON-GUI
Samples (threads): 10
Min: 1114
Max: 1226
```

I've repeated the requests several times, but the results are consistent even with higher numbers of threads (100-150). I have disabled all other threads/listeners for the non-gui mode, and in GUI mode I only use Aggregate report.
Did I miss something?

Comment: Hello, Any feedback on answer ? If answer is ok, you should accept it and upvote. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are following possible explanations:

- In Non GUI mode, injection is not parasitized by handling of GUI by Awt-thread or listeners management. So JMeter would be injecting correctly expected load and leading to degraded response times from your server
- Your are load testing from a different machine in non gui mode, in this case check you are really in same configuration (jvm, jmeter, machine, network)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am using the same project file in both gui and non-gui mode, and same server/workstation from which I run the tests from. The only difference being that in GUI mode I have an Aggregate Report listener. When testing in non-gui mode, I disable the listener from the thread group. I was expecting the same (or better) response times in non-gui mode because the lack of listeners, but I get the opposite and I don't know which results should I rely on.

Comment: The non gui results are the most accurate ones. If answer is ok, you should accept it and upvote. Thanks